# Determine if UIView is contained within screens bounds

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

if I have a view, how can I determine if its frame is contained within the visible screen?

I currently have this but it is very sketchy and not robust at all.

```
var newPoint = (this.ConvertPointFromView(new PointF(newX, newY), UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View));

if (newPoint.X + _infoBox.Frame.Width > UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Frame.Width
    || newPoint.Y + _infoBox.Frame.Height + _glass.Frame.Height > UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Frame.Height)
    {
            //.....
    }
```

Comment: To compare if one rect is completely inside a seconf rect you can you the CGRectContainsRect(rect2, rect1))  function

Comment: @iKatalan ok, but then I assume that they will need to be in the same space then. What I mean is, how can I get the view's dimensions in relation to the screen

Comment: @DavidPilkington, did you ever get this to work in C# (Xamarin)? I see the solutions below are not C# and Xamarin does not offer CGRectContainsRect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare if one rect is completely inside a seconf rect you can use CGRectContainsRect(rect2, rect1)) function

Like this: CGRectContainsRect([ [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds], Infobox.frame)

I'm not so into swift syntax but that should be easy to convert.

Edit:
Use convertRect to get infobox in screen coordinates. Passing nil as the view: argument.
[Infobox convertRect: infobox.bounds view:nil]

from mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGRectContainsPoint routine to check whether a rect is inside another rect or not.

```
CGRect rect = yourView.frame;
BOOL flag =  CGRectContainsRect(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds,rect);
if (flag) {
    NSLog(@"indside screen bounds");
}else{
    NSLog(@"not in screen bounds");
}
```

Edited:
    CGRect frame = [yourView convertRect:rect fromView:nil];

Comment: The other issue is that I need to get the reactangle of the view in  relation to the screens dimensions. How can I do that?

Comment: @DavidPilkington  read the diffrence between bounds and frame property, and try to get rectangle, like from center property of view.